# data transfer form1 to form2 and also retrieve data from database win form app C#

Tags: forms, c#-4.0, window

I have two form 1 and 2. form1 contain 1 textbox and 1 button.when I type client ID in textbox and click on button  form2 open and fill up form2 with client record from database .Form 2 contain 5 textbox and one datatime picker
Need simple code

Comment: Have you tried anything? show your efforts.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. An example of a good question would be one where you've tried some code, provided a snippet of the work you've done and reason why you are stuck or getting errors.